# Split branch in two branches / Merge a branch selectively

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a repo in git in which I started working in a new branch to develop a feature. When it was halfways done, I noticed a bug which I hotfixed. But instead of commiting the hotfix to master and rebasing the development branch, I commited to the development branch. This has happened several times in a row, and now I realize my mistake.

I want to do another hotfix over master, but the hotfix depends on the previous hotfixes, and I cannot fully merge the development branch as there are a ton of untested changes.

So, here is my question: how can I merge only those commits including hotfixes to master, while leaving the untested commits in the developement branch?

To be more specific, the commits I want to merge and those I want to preserve in the other branch are intercalated.

Graphically, my repo looks like this, where H are hotfixes and D untested commits:

```
devbranch     D1 - H1 - D2 - H2
             /
master A - B
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
devbranch              D1 - D2
                      /
master A - B - H1 - H2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cherry pick the commits you want to master, then rebase your feature branch to the new master.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick H1
git cherry-pick H2
git checkout devbranch
git rebase master
```

Comment: Would not cherry picking leave copies of H1 and H2 in devbranch?

Comment: @Jsevillamol: It would, but they'll disappear in the rebase.